# Stolen iPhone - check status of Find My iPhone

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4s was stolen but im not sure if the Find My iPhone was switched on.
The phone number is still the same and active.

Is it possible to check the status?

Answer (score 12):

Go to https://www.icloud.com/#find to check the status.

From there you can track where it currently is or was last seen, make it play a sound, lock it by enabling Lost Mode [which includes adding another phone number to the lock screen you can be contacted at], or even erase it [though that would disable Find My iPhone]

Comment: But I thought his question was "Can I find out if Find My iPhone was enabled?" Not how to use Find My iPhone.

Comment: @Almo It is, but he can find out if Find My iPhone is enabled or not by seeing if he has the options for the lost iPhone on the find page

Comment: Ok, maybe clarify that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/#find).
From there you can make it play a sound, lock it by enabling *Lost mode*.

Comment: Can you explain what this adds over the prior sentence?   This looks like a complete subset of the previous answer.  If there is an existing answer and you don't have anything to add, there might not be much point in adding a new answer.  Also, we generally prefer detailed answers with explanations or justification, where possible.